# if i called shutdown(fd,SHUT_RDWR),but not called close(fd),what will happen?

Tags: sockets

if i called shutdown(fd,SHUT_RDWR),but not called close(fd),what will happen?

```
inline void CSocket::close()
{
    if (_socket_fd != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        ::shutdown(_socket_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
        ::close(_socket_fd);
        _socket_fd = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
}
```

Comment: I means it will result in deplete the operating system descriptor?

Comment: +1 `shutdown()` tells the operating system that a socket will no longer be read from and/or written to.  Note that this is an and/or as you can specify that only one direction of communication gets shutdown.  `close()` on the other hand frees all resources associated with a socket (or any open file-like-thing behind a file descriptor).  This includes the file descriptor itself as well as buffers, or other resources associated with the socket.

Comment: sorry,it should result in deplete process descriptor,not os descriptor.

Comment: Believe it or not, there's a global limit on the number of file descriptors that can be active at once in the kernel.  This is one of the reasons why there are process-level limits:  To prevent this kernel limit from being exhausted by a single process, or by processes run by normal users.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84227/limits-on-the-number-of-file-descriptors for details.

Comment: `close` does NOT free all resources, otherwise `shutdown` would be worthless.

Comment: @o11c `close()` *does* free all resources, *and* `shutdown()` is not worthless. Possibly you meant the other way round?

Comment: @o11c: `shutdown` tells the kernel "no more of this type of operation will occur from my end".  This potentially frees up read/write/or both buffers in the kernel, and also signals the other end of the socket.  If the other end is `select`ing on this socket for reading and/or writing, the types of operations `shutdown` was told will not happen again may cause that `select` to unblock, allowing the other end of the connection to gracefully terminate instead of waiting (for the opportunity to read/write data) indefinitely.  `disconnect` disconnects, and`close` forcefully frees up the socket&fd.

Answer (score -1):

> if i called shutdown(fd,SHUT_RDWR),but not called close(fd),what will happen?

- On the network, a FIN will be sent, which will cause the peer to encounter end of stream after reading any pending data.
- Future `recv()` and `read()` calls in your socket will return zero, indicating end of stream.
- You will not be able to send from this socket.
- What happens if the peer tries to send you more data is system-dependent: if your platform is Windows a reset will be issued; if it is Unix the data will be acknowledged and thrown away; if it is Linux the data will be acknowledged and uselessly saved in your socket receiver buffer, from whence you can never retrieve it, and which will eventually close your receive window and prevent the peer from sending.
- the socket descriptor is not closed or released to the operating system.

Comment: Of course something happens on the network. Since this call also closes the _writing_ side of the socket, a FIN packet is sent to the peer to indicate that. A pending or subsequent `read()` calls at the peer socket will return EOF then (on common socket interfaces, POSIX for example).